# How to fix and Debugging parallel array bubblesort program?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Another coder has added a bunch of pointers to code I wrote earlier without apparent reason. This should perform a simple bubblesort via functions. Are the pointers in any of the functions necessary, in particular the age function? How can I get this program to run?

```
#define SIZE 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
void bubblesortname(char fullname[][25], int *age, int size);
void bubblesortage(char fullname[], int *age, int size);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char fullname[SIZE][25];
    int age[SIZE];

    // promt user for names and ages
    input(fullname, age);
    //output unsorted names and ages
    output(fullname, age);

    bubblesortname(fullname,age,SIZE);    
    output(fullname, age);

    //sorts age
    bubblesortage(fullname,age,SIZE);
    output(fullname, age);

    return 0;
}

void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter a full name\n");
        //scanf("%[\^n]\n", fullname[i]);
        fgets (fullname[i],40, stdin);
        printf("Enter the age\n");
        scanf("%d", &age[i]);                
    }
}

void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%s, %d\n", fullname[i], age[i]);
}

void bubblesortname(char fullname[][], int *age, int size)
{
    int temp_age;
    char* temp_name;
    int j,i;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++j) 
        {
            if (strcmp(fullname[j], fullname[j + 1]) > 0) 
            {
                temp_age = age[i];
                age[j] = age[j + 1];
                age[j + 1] = temp_age;
                temp_name = fullname[j];
                fullname[j] = fullname[j + 1];
                fullname[j + 1] = temp_name;    
            }        
        }       
    }        
}

bubblesortage(char fullname[][], int *age, int size) 
{
    int j,i;
    int temp_age;
    char* temp_name;
    char temp[25];

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) 
        {
            if (age[j] > age[j + 1]) 
            {
                strcpy(temp, fullname[<index1>]);
                strcpy(fullname[index1], fullname[index2]);
                strcpy(fullname[index2], temp);
                temp_age = age[j];
                age[j] = age[j + 1];
                age[j + 1] = temp_age;
                temp_name = fullname[j];
                fullname[j] = fullname[j + 1];
                fullname[j + 1] = temp_name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to review your code and make recommendations if you add comments to point out the exact places you're querying about

Comment: Ok thats a good point

Comment: Try to avoid even remotely slandering other engineers: assume the best intentions. Also, please format your code for maximum readability. Finally, as a stylistic concern: comments that repeat the semantic meaning of code aren't useful: `//end inner for` for instance. This actually clutters up your code and make it take longer to read and understand, rather than make it clearer (which is the point of comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the pointers in any of the functions necessary

If you use C, pointers are necessary. In C strings represented by pointers. Arrays in C is represented by pointers too. So you can't avoid them.

But if you use c++, it is not necessary. You can use `std::vector` or any other container class that fits your task best.

Anyway, it is not necessary duplicate bubble sort implementation many times. You can write generic function using function pointer like `qsort()` does.

> How can I get this program to run?

Code contains many syntactical errors. You should fix them all for run. But it is not guaranteed that code works correctly.